# Deleted Search Service Index for QNA, how to recreate?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-qna-maker

1. I have a QnAMaker account.
2. I deleted an index in Azure Search Service.
3. Then in QNA Maker it shows:

```
Azure search service error
Runtime error. Unable to connect to Azure search service. Please verify that the Azure search resource in your QnAMaker service is up and running.
```

4. How can I recreate the index for my QnA?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below steps solved the issue.

- Go to QnAhost app service.
- Update the following entries under 'Configuration'.

  - AzureSearchAdminKey
  - AzureSearchName